# Registrar várias imagens no banco de dados na mesma linha | Mysql | PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Não estou conseguindo fazer o registro de várias nomes de imagens separados por virgulas  em uma coluna de uma linha, estou conseguindo fazer os uploads múltiplos, mas cada nome de imagem fica registrada em uma linha diferente do banco de dados. E queria tipo assim: o usuário faz o upload de 5 fotos e todas as imagens inseridas na mesma coluna da mesma linha, cada uma separadas por vírgula no banco de dados:

```
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ID | img
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1 | image(1).jpg, image(2).jpg, image(3).jpg, image(4).jpg, image(5).jpg
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Aqui está o Formulário:**

```
<form action="public.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="images[]" accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg" multiple />
     <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Segue o código PHP:**

```
$fotoPost = $_FILES['images']; //recebe as imagens passadas pelo input file
$numFoto = count(array_filter($fotoPost['name'])); //conta quantas imagens foram inseridas no input

$folder = "../../arquivs/postagensImg/$dash/"; // pasta do arquivo
$extensao= array('image/jpeg', 'image/png'); // extensões permitidas
$maxSite = 1024 * 1024 * 5; // tamanho máximo da foto

$new_name = substr(sha1(time()).rand().md5(time()), - 40).".".$extensao; novo nome para imagem

for($i=0; $i < $numFoto; $i++){ //estrutura de repetição, só que isso vai adicionando várias linhas
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder.$new_name)){
        $sqlInImg = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO postagem ( img, datePost) VALUES ('$new_name', NOW())");
            if($sqlInImg == true){
                $_SESSION['successPost'] = "Imagem postada com Sucesso";
                header("Location: ../direcao.php");
            }else{
                unlink("../../arquivs/postagensImg/$new_name");
                $_SESSION['errPost'] = "Desculpe, erro ao postar imagem";
                header("Location: ../direcao.php");
            }
        }else{
            $_SESSION['errPost'] = "Error ao adicionar imagem na pasta";
            header("Location: ../direcao.php");
        }
}
```

Tentarei fazer aqui com o implode(), caso eu consiga respondo aqui como eu fiz

Comment: Eu tô ligado que parece que dá para fazer oque pretendo com o implode(), mas alguém poderia me mostrar como mais ou menos?

Comment: Coloca na pergunta a parte do formulario e o php

Comment: Já consegui fazer o que eu queria, vou colocar agora a resposta que consegui encontrar, foi mais fácil do que pensei, pesquisei na própria cachola kkkkkk

Answer (score 1):

No loop for você constrói a variavel para ser inserida no banco

```
$nome = ($_FILES['images']['name'][$i]);

$values .= $nome.",";
```

Depois do loop

```
//retira a ultima virgula
$values=substr($values, 0, -1);
```

//declaração insert

```
....... VALUES ('$values',NOW()......
```

Answer (score 0):

Felizmente consegui a solução para minha questão, o problema eu sabia desde o início que era a repetição da inserção no banco de dados, mas deixei por que ainda não sabia o que devia alterar para poder solucionar, então consegui resolver meu problema com o implode. Lá vai a solução que consegui para quem precisar inserir vários dados na mesma linha e coluna do banco de dados separado apenas por ",":

O formulario continua o mesmo... O php é o seguinte:

```
$foto = $_FILES['image']; // Capturo as imagens enviadas pelo input[file]
$cont = count(array_filter($foto['name'])); // Faço a filtragem das imagens que foram enviadas como array e conto quantos imagens foram enviadas

for ($i=0; $i < $cont; $i++) { // Aqui é o Macete, faço uma estrutura de repetição 
//<code>for</code>, ele vai comparar a minha variável $i de valor inicial "0", 
//e se for menor do que o $cont, ele vai adicionar até igualar a contagem, 
//ou seja, vai pegar cada nome do array de acordo com a sua posição no array $name[$i] 
//e vai incrementar toda vez que o for é executado no implode, então suas imagens 
///já estarão todas adicionas juntamente em uma única variável separadas por vírgula,
//agora basta apenas registrar no bando de dados


    $name[$i] = $foto['name'];
    $implode = implode(', ', $name[$i]);
}
```

Comment: E para separar elas para exibi-las, basta apenas separá-las com o explode(", ")...

Comment: e para publicar na pasta? faz outro loop for?